# Android- Setting Wallpaper and save image error?

Tags: android, eclipse, button, imageview, wallpaper

Hi i would like to know if anyone knows a tutorial on ow to set an image as and wallpaper with the click of an Button

I tried using wallpaper manager, it worked but when i add my code to save the image to sdcard/internal it give me and error. 
Does anyone know any other way?
Thanks
All help appreciated

Comment: This question needs a lot more information for anyone to help you. "it gives me an error" what error does it give you? When does the error occur (in what line of code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add the permission for the SDCARD ?

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: Yes I going to put the error up now

Comment: it didnt help but i just wanted to give you rep, thanks anyways!